# SCSS error : identifier expected && { expected

Tags: css, sass

I just opened this file but error appeard. I don't know how to solve it.

main.scss

```
---
# Only the main Sass file needs front matter (the dashes are enough)
---

@charset "utf-8";

@import "minimal-mistakes/skins/{{ site.minimal_mistakes_skin | default: 'default' }}"; // skin
@import "minimal-mistakes"; // main partials
```

[image]
[image]

I did nothing..
Try to search about 'scss/css identifier expected' or 'scss/css { expected error'
But there were no information about it..

Thank you for your help

Comment: Looks like you're using a incorrect syntax for your comments. You could comment from line 1 to 4 using `/* ... */`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to install minimal-mistakes jekyll theme to your github pages.

I had the same problem. I could not deploy my website to github pages and thought that the problem had something to do with main.scss file, because the error said "Scss encountered an error while converting 'assets/css/main.scss'". But it was not the problem.

The problem was that 'vendor' was in my .gitignore file. When I removed it, the deployment was successful. Hope this resolves your problem as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).